# Не работает переменная g[r]

Tags: javascript

Вот код:

```
<script>
var r=1;
    var g[1]='fff';
    alert(g[r]);
</script>
```

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var r=1,
    g = {};
g[1]='fff';
alert(g[r]);
```

у тебя g не является объектом, поэтому и возникает ошибка

Comment: а, если написать g = [] будет возникать эта же ошибка?

Comment: не будет. будет работать. помоему самому быстрее было проверить, чем сюда постить вопрос =)

Comment: я всего лишь уточнил)

Comment: Работает. Спасибо.